# Не пускает в админку роутера с одного компа, с другого без проблем

Tags: wifi, router, админка, tp-link

Дано:

1. Роутер TP-LINK TL-WR840N(RU)
2. comp A, подключенный к роутеру через кабель
3. comp B, подключенный к роутеру через wifi
4. захожу с comp A в админку роутера по адресу tplinkwifi.net
5. с comp B админка не открывается ни по адресу tplinkwifi.net, ни по 192.168.1.1 (при tracert с этого компа именно этот адрес высвечивается первым)

Вопрос: где искать проблему? Связано ли это с тем, что comp B подключен по вайфаю? Хотя в инете читал, что это не должно быть помехой. А может из-за того, что подключен по гостевому вайфаю? Тогда как сделать comp B не гостевым, а "своим"? В настройках роутера ковырялся, но не разобрался как сделать "своим".

Comment: Некоторые роутеры запрещают входить в настройки иначе, чем через кабель. Возможно, ваш роутер из таких.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что comp B находился в гостевом вайфае. Переподключил его к основному вайфаю, доступ к роутеру появился.